# Not equals when using CASE statement in SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, case

In postgresql, I have a `case` statement that I need to add a "not equals" clause.

When `v1` equals v2, I want it to say 1, when `v1` **DOES NOT EQUAL** `v2`, I would like to say 2.

```
create table test (
v1      varchar(20),
v2      varchar(20)
);

insert into test values ('Albert','Al'),('Ben','Ben')

select case v1
when v2 then 1
    else 3
end 
from test
```

I tried using `!=` or `<>`, but that does not seem to work.

Does anyone have any idea how to use not equals in a `case` statement in SQL?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could always just be more explicit with your case statement.  Here's an example...

```
    select 
      case when v1 = v2 then 1
       when v1 <> v2 then 2
      end
    from test
```

Comment: @Trexion, feel free to change the Answer to Nicholas Carey's excellent and detailed explanation below.  I won't mind.

Answer (score 3):

First, you start by [reading the documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/static/functions-conditional.html). You'll note that the SQL `case` function takes one of two forms:

```
case {expression}
  when {value-1} then {result-1}
  ...
  when {value-N} then {result-N}
[ else {default-result} ]
end
```

or

```
case
  when {boolean-condition-1} then {result-1}
  ...
  when {boolean-condition-N} then {result-N}
[ else {default-result]
end
```

So, you can say something like

```
select * ,
       case
         when v1  = v2                          then 1
         when v1 != v2                          then 2
         when v1 is     null and v2 is not null then 2
         when v1 is not null and v2 is     null then 2
         else 1 -- both v1 and v2 are null
       end as are_equal
from test
```

Note that

- You cannot mix the two forms, and
- The `else` clause is optional: ifnot specified, the return value from the function for any values not matching a `when` clause is `null`, nad
- Because `null` fails all tests save for explicit tests for nullity via `is [not] null`, if you need to check for `null`, you either have to use the 2nd form (`... case when x is null then y else z end`) or have the null fall through and be handled by an `else` clause.

Comment: This is a great explanation of the two forms.  I tend to use the boolean form as it is a bit more flexible.

Answer (score 0):

What you have appears to be working.  You can also use `!=` or `<>`.

```
select case 
  when v1 != v2 then 2
  else 1
  end 
from test

select case 
  when v1 <> v2 then 2
  else 1
  end 
from test
```

SQLFiddles:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/f5cac/5
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/f5cac/7